# Log - vb.net to java

Tags: java, vb.net

Can anybody explain what Log means in vb.net code? Is it the Logarithm function or some other log event. I did some search on this and I understood that this was for the Logarithm part. However, I do not understand the below line of code if I apply Logarithm to it.

```
tmp=pBuffer(5)+4
Log("tmp:" & tmp)
```

Can anyone explain this line of code and what is the equivalent java for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line of code looks to be logging an event to a log file (or console) rather than the Logarithm mathematical operation.

There are many ways to do logging in Java, but the simplest (though not the nicest) is to do the following:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Example {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Example.class.getName());

    static void doStuff(int[] pBuffer) {
        int tmp = pBuffer[5] + 4;
        log.info("tmp:" + tmp);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        doStuff(new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
    }
}
```

I've translated your example code verbatim as the function `doStuff`. If you run it, you'll get something like the following printed to the console:

```
12 17, 2012 4:47:01 PM Example doStuff
INFO: tmp:9
```

This code uses Java's built-in logging facility, which I have not used. If you need sophisticated logging functionality, I recommend [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org) or [log4j](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4j).

Comment: thanks for the answer. What is "Logger" in your code? Is it part of java API? I understand your answer that the log in my line of code is basically to print the result, am I right?

Comment: ah, sorry. forgot the imports statement! I've added it. Logger is `java.util.logging.Logger`, part of the Java API. Yes, your line of code looks like logging, but only you can know for sure. :)

Answer (score 1):

This Log means log event,I think.
Just for print the  **tmp** value.